# Is it possible to create multiple instances of OMXCodec using stagefright

Tags: android, stagefright, openmax

I want to use `libstagefright.so` in android phones for media operations. I have explored example given in [this](http://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk)  page. I have been trying to implement the same. While testing this implementation for multiple  `OMXCodec` instances, it's output buffer conflicts with each other.

I have developed an android project in eclipse and linked `libstagefright` under JNI. I have added two classes `CustomDataSource` (Which derives `MediaSource`) and `CustomOmxDecoder`. `CustomDataSource` class implements all virtual methods of `MediaSource`. In `CustomOmxDecoder` class, I call `OMXCodec::Create` method. Then I have created two threads which have individual instance of `CustomOmxDecoder`. Using this instances I call a method `ProcessNextFrame` in which I call the main, `videoDecoder->read()` method. This is how my setup is.

Now, When I run the app with above mentioned setup. `OMXCodec` decodes frames of both source but when I render it on surface, is shows me conflicted output. It seems like decoded buffer of both source get meshed up internally somehow. I am creating two h264 decoder simultaneously. What can be the problem here? Can it be related to `MediaBufferGroup`? I acquirebuffer in `CustomDataSource` and release buffer in `CustomOmxDecoder`'s `ProcessNextFrame` after calling `videoDecoder->read()` call.

Any suggestion will be great.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using `allocateOutputBuffersfromNativeWindow`, then you need to check `nativeWindow` or `surface` passed to the creation of the decoders. From your comment, I feel you are passing the same `surface` to both the instances of the decoder due to which you might be observing the incorrect images. Can you check if your logic works fine for one instance of the decoder only?

Comment: actually i do not pass surface as a parameter while creating omxcodec instance. and i checked surface addresses. they are different. even i did one more test in which i added a condition in my decode display method, in customomxdecoder class , such that for thread one decoded buffer is rendered on given surface and for thread two, frame will be decoded but surface will render black color only. in this case also picture gets conflicts in first surface ans second surface display black.

Comment: do you think that videosource->read(&buffer,&option) method need to be covered between auto lock / mutex?

Comment: Ganesh, your guess was in right direction. Not the surface but there was another parameter in my code which was same for both thread. And hence it proves that multiple instance of omxcodec is possible. I apologies for my post. and will remove this thread in some time as it can waste someone't time. Thanks.

Comment: Sam.. I am happy that you found your bug. I have tried multi-instance codecs, in couple of use-cases. However, I didn't program much on Java level. Do you plan to delete this post?

Comment: thanks a lot ganesh for your efforts. i have planned todelete it but if you want it to remain than i wont. let me know if it can be helpful

Comment: I was thinking that we could answer this question that multi-instance codec is possible and we should look at sync mechanism to root-cause the issue. This way it could be helpful for someone else who might be looking for a similar issue. What do you feel?

Comment: okay  . . i am not gonna remove this post.

Comment: Would you answer your own post or shall I answer?

Comment: Thanks keeping it not deleted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested and solved my issue, doubting that multiple instances of OMXCodec is possible. The issue was in my code. And on fixing up, I can see OMXCodec's mulitple instance running stable and smooth. So, Yes, Mulitple instances of OMXCodec is possbile.

Thank you all.